# Converting string into new Image XAML C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a string of a location for an image, and I'm trying to create a XAML Image object, change the source to the string, and append it to a stackpanel.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage tmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
tmp.UriSource = new Uri("Assets/image.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
Image image = new Image();
image.Source = tmp;
```

The problem is that I can't seem to convert System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage to Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource.

I'm using that code pretty much directly off the Microsoft MSDN website, and I can't understand why it's not working. I've also tried creating an ImageSource object and I just can't seem to get anything to work. It's frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Displaying `Image`s from `string` file paths is easy in WPF. First, ensure that the files have been added into the project using Visual Studio's *Add Existing Item* command so that it adds the image files with a *Build Action* value of *Resource*. Next, you need to use the correct file path. It is best if you refer to the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for full details, but you can use this format pretty much everywhere in your application:

```
pack://application:,,,/ProjectOrAssemblyName;component/SubFolderName/ImageName.png
```

To display that image, you can simply set that value to a `string` property and data bind it to an `Image.Source` property in the UI, or use it directly:

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourImageSource}" />
```

...

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/
    ProjectOrAssemblyName;component/SubFolderName/ImageName.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I can't seem to convert
>   System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage to
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource.

As per ImageSource reference it seems you are using WinRT app and not WPF.

You should use `Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` if you are targeting WinRT app.
`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` meant to be used from WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try this:

```
BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat imgFormat)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Save(memory, imgFormat);
                memory.Position = 0;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
                bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                bitmapImage.EndInit();

                return bitmapImage;
            }
        }
```

(source: http://pastebin.com/PAJ7Cd0x)

Regards,